# Deploy Azure functions as IoT Edge modules how to observe difference?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I was following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-function) (on Ubuntu 1604).

In the end I was able to get everything working. However I could not get the difference in observation.

When I was running azure function as C# function it was reporting temperature even less than 25 (verified using `iotedgectl logs -f tempsensor`) for machine to iot hub with tempsensor module.

This is the same behaviour as if I simple run of tempsensor.

How can I observe the difference with introduction of azure function?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please proofread your question(s) and learn how to properly format code. Thanks. And have fun!

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure functions as IoT Edge modules tutorial, it will filter messages based on the temperature value in the body of the message and the temperature threshold value, the threshold value is 25. You can see the `routes` in the deployment json file. The `tempSensor` module is just sending the random generated data. So when you use `iotedgectl logs -f tempsensor` command, you will find all the data. You need to check the log of azure function module,or edgeHub or monitor the C2D message to IoTHub to verify the filter feature.

```
        "routes": {
          "sensorToCSharpFunction": "FROM /messages/modules/tempSensor/outputs/temperatureOutput INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/CSharpFunction/inputs/input1\")",
          "CSharpFunctionToIoTHub": "FROM /messages/modules/CSharpFunction/outputs/output1 INTO $upstream"
        },
```